# Getting NLog to send out JSON with proper headers?

Tags: c#, json, logging, couchdb, nlog

Trying to use NLog to send JSON-encoded logs out of our C# app, to dump them into CouchDB. However, using the Network target, I can't seem to find a way to set the Content-Type header properly; and CouchDB won't have anything to do with my input otherwise.

CouchDB is out-of-the-box, Current NLog config:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="true">
    <variable name="FileLayout" value='{ "date":"${longdate}","level":"${level}","message":${message}}' />
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="Network" address="http://127.0.0.1:5984/logger/" layout="${FileLayout}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

And the raw HTTP (hostnames edited):

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/logger/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
Content-Length: 221
Expect: 100-continue

{ "date":"2011-08-12 13:38:06.4603","level":"Info","message":{"backlog":0, "too_busy":0, "io_threads":1000, "threads":32766, "messages_processed":0}, "ProcessName": "foobar"}
```

Comment: Please post what you have in terms of code and configuration for both the app and CoucheDb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the `HttpNetworkSender` [source](https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Internal/NetworkSenders/HttpNetworkSender.cs), I don't see an obvious way to pass in a content type to the `WebRequest`.

I think you will have to create a custom target based on the `NetworkTarget` which uses a custom `HttpNetworkSender`, and include config to set the content-type on the `WebRequest` Appropriately.

Comment: Or if you want to get really crazy, you could try and embed the entire HTTP Conversation into the layout, and then set the address to TCP.  Not sure if that would work, might be interesting though.

Comment: Patching HttpNetworkSender was easy enough, that did the trick.

Comment: Would you mind contributing the patch to the community? I am having the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

NLog ver. 4.5 WebService Target has the ability to configure custom headers.

```
<target xsi:type="WebService"
         name="CouchDB"
         url="http://127.0.0.1:5984/logger/"
         protocol="JsonPost"
         encoding="utf-8">
      <parameter layout="FileLayout" />
      <header name="Content-Type" layout="application/json" />
</target>
```

See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still stumble on this, here is simple demo for custom http target (NLog v4.x.x).

```
public class WebPostTarget : Target
{
    public string ServerUrl { get; set; }
    private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        PostData(new [] { logEvent.AsLogModel() }); 
    }

    protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
    {
        var data = logEvents.Select(x => x.LogEvent.AsLogModel()).ToArray();
        PostData(data);
    }

    private void PostData(object data)
    {
        if (!ServerUrl.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            // add your custom headers to the client if you need to 
            _client.PostJsonAsync(ServerUrl, data).FireAndForget();
        }
    }
}
// HttpClientExtensions
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync(this HttpClient client, string url, object data)
{
    return await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(data.ToJson(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

From configuration code:

```
var asyncWebTarget = new AsyncTargetWrapper()
{
    Name = "web_batch_logServer",
    BatchSize = 100,
    TimeToSleepBetweenBatches = 1000,
    OverflowAction = AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Grow,
    WrappedTarget = new WebPostTarget { ServerUrl = logServerUrl }
};
```