# using Nlog and writing to file as json

Tags: json, nlog

I think I'm missing something as I can't seem to figure out how to have it write to a log file in json format using NLog setup in configuration file.  The straight rolling file works fine, but not the json.  The json target only outputs the message (not in json).

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">        
    <targets async="true">
      <target xsi:type="File" name="rollingFile" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log" archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/{shortdate}_Archive{###}.log" archiveAboveSize="1000000" archiveNumbering="Sequence" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite} ${message}" />
      <target xsi:type="File" 
              name="rollingFileJson" 
              fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.json" 
              archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/{shortdate}_Archive{###}.json" 
              archiveAboveSize="1000000" 
              archiveNumbering="Sequence" 
              layout="${json-encode} ${message}">
      </target>

    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="rollingFile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="rollingFileJson" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Answer (score 16):

As of the release of NLog 4.0.0 it is possible to use a layout that renders events as structured JSON documents.

Example taken from [NLog project site](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html):

```
<target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logFileNamePrefix}.json">
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
</target>
```

**Edit:**
You can also create it in code.

[Here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout#from-the-api) is the link to the specific part of documentation.

And here the copied example:

```
var jsonLayout = new JsonLayout
{
    Attributes =
    {
        new JsonAttribute("type", "${exception:format=Type}"),
        new JsonAttribute("message", "${exception:format=Message}"),
        new JsonAttribute("innerException", new JsonLayout
        {

            Attributes =
            {
                new JsonAttribute("type", "${exception:format=:innerFormat=Type:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator=}"),
                new JsonAttribute("message", "${exception:format=:innerFormat=Message:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator=}"),
            }
        },
        //don't escape layout
        false)
    }
};
```

For more info read the [docs](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout).

Comment: Any way of doing this in a programmatic way?

Comment: @user3841581 Added an example taken from the documentation to do it in code.

Answer (score 3):

As per [NLog documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JSON-Encode-Layout-Renderer): **json-encode** will only **escape output** of another layout using JSON rules. It will not "convert" the output to JSON. You'll have to do that yourself.

```
'{ "date":"${longdate}","level":"${level}","message":${message}}'
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044308/getting-nlog-to-send-out-json-with-proper-headers) for more details.