# NLog - Indented/pretty formatted JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find an answer to this, but how do I get NLog to write JSON formatted messages in a pretty format, instead of the default one-line version?

Is there a simple setting somewhere or do I need to write a custom renderer?

Basically instead of

`{ "date": "2018-11-18 14:21:45.0671", "level": "INFO", "message": "Some message" }`

I'd like

```
{
  "date": "2018-11-18 14:21:45.0671",
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "Some message"
}
```

Comment: Yes NLog only has support for valid JSON (without newlines). Maybe try `JToken.Parse(rawJsonString).ToString()`

Comment: @RolfKristensen do you mean try that as part of a custom renderer?

Comment: are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31382683/4572240 ?

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex thanks, but no. This layout is what gives me the one-liner i mentioned. There doesn't seem to be a setting to render it in a pretty format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog v5.1.4 has been released - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.1.4, that extends [JsonLayout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout) with the setting `indentJson="true"`:

```xml
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target name="jsonConsole" xsi:type="Console">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeEventProperties="true" indentJson="true">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}" />
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="jsonConsole" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Ah, that's awesome! I'll see if I'll be able to try it out in the near future, but this looks exactly like what I needed.