# Format JSON object in Console or File targets of NLog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

For a simple prototype program, I am using NLog with ColoredConsole and File targets, with simple layouts (see configuration file below).

And I am using `@` operator to destructure objects :

```
Logger.Debug("values : {@result}", aRandomObject);
```

where aRandomObject could be anything.

Unfortunately, for both the Console and File targets, by default the destructured object is rendered in json without any formatting. Pretty convienient for computers, but much harder to read for humans.

Instead, I would like to find a way to print my objects as formatted json (with indentations and line breaks) if it's possible with Nlog.

I don't want to render the whole target as a json (as a "JsonLayout" allows), but only the objects logged with @.

Here's the full NLog configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:/temp/nlog-internal.log">

    <variable name="baseLogDirectory" value="C:\Logs\Thing"/>

    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="${baseLogDirectory}\${cached:cached=true:inner=${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}}_${processid}.log"
                layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite} ${message} ${exception:format=toString,Data}" />

        <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${longdate}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${message}" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file, console" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Thank you

Comment: NLog JsonSerializer currently doesn't support pretty-formatted/indented JSON. I guess you can go old-school and provide a `IFormatProvider`-implementation as input, that knows how to format your object in pretty-format.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53361324/193178

Comment: NLog v5.1.4 has been released - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.1.4 where `JsonLayout` now has `IndentJson`-option.